# Set input relative to map rotation?

Tags: c#, unity, rigidbody

I'm trying to figure out how I can make the input which looks like this :

```
    // Checks if player is pressing movement keys, if is applies force to specified direction
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        //rigid.AddForce(new Vector2(-speed * Time.deltaTime, 0));
        rigid.AddRelativeForce(Vector2.left);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
        //rigid.AddForce(new Vector2(speed * Time.deltaTime, 0));
        rigid.AddRelativeForce(Vector2.right);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) && groundCheck.isGrounded == false || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && groundCheck.isGrounded == false || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && groundCheck.isGrounded == false)
    {
        groundCheck.isGrounded = false;
        //rigid.AddRelativeForce(new Vector2(0, jumpPower));
        rigid.velocity = new Vector2(rigid.velocity.x, jumpPower);
    }
```

Always move according to the maps rotation.

So, even if the map were to rotate the player doesn't get inverted inputs (player is children of map, so it rotates too) :

Right now A is always to left, according to the players position, but if the player would rotate 90 degrees the input would be wrong, Left would be up/down, but I want it to still be left.

---

Here's a picture example : (Sorry for the horrible painting, I blame mouse :> )

[image: Image!]

---

I do want the physics in the world to not change when I rotate the world.

So if the player is rotated 90 degrees it should fall to the side instead of down. :D

Comment: Sounds like you want the input to be in *world space*, rather than *object/local space*.  Therefore use `AddForce()` rather than `AddRelativeForce()`.

Answer (score 0):

The key is knowing current world rotation, you need to maintain it as you rotate e.g.:

```
double worldRotation;

void rotateWorldLeft()
{
   worldRotation = (worldRotation + 90) % 360;
}
```

then, when moving the character, just [Rotate](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/661383/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-rotate-a-vector2-o.html) the `Vector2`s along e.g.:

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
{
    rigid.AddRelativeForce(Vector2.left.Rotate(worldRotation));
}
```

Alternatively, if you have only few and known in advance possible rotations, you could use lookup table coupled with enum and modulus:

```
Enum Direction { Up = 0, Left, Bottom, Right }

Vector2[] Directions = { Vector2.up, Vector2.left, -Vector2.up, Vector2.right };

Direction worldOrientation; /*again keep it up-to date*/
...
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
{
   rigid.AddRelativeForce(Directions[((int)Direction.Left + (int)worldOrientation) % Directions.Length]);
}
```

*note: the first solution should be preferred, casting enum to int is not the best practice - I am mentioning this only should you prefer avoid vector math completely*

Comment: 'Vector2' does not contain a definition for 'Rotate' and no extension method 'Rotate' accepting a first argument of type 'Vector2' could be   Uh, adding Rotate after Vector2.left doesn't work :<

Comment: To be clear, you are rotating the camera and not the world right?  Adjust your input using the Y axis rotation as input angle offset.

Comment: @RobStone No, I'm rotating the world so I still have the same physics as I had before the world was rotated. (also, the player is a part of the world so it gets rotated as well.)

Comment: @RobStone I guess rotating the camera could work too. But I would still have the same problems.

Comment: @BiiX ofcourse there is no .Rotate in Unity, thats why I linked(in case you couldnt find it on google) you the implementation of extension method. Just follow the link under "rotate".

Comment: @wondra Didn't notice the link. I will check it out asap.